# Equality comparison between Date and number doesn't work

Tags: javascript, comparison, date-comparison, value-of, type-coercion

According to the ECMA script standard, the following code should return true, but it doesn't:

```
d = new Date() ;
d.setTime(1436497200000) ;
alert( d == 1436497200000 ) ;
```

Section [11.9.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) says:

> 8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).

Then, section [8.12.8](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.12.8) says that `ToPrimitive` retuns the result of the `valueOf` method. Which means that the last line in my example above should be equivalent to:

```
alert( d.valueOf() == 1436497200000 );
```

Which does return `true`, indeed.

Why does the first case not return `true`?

Comment: the 1st one compares an object to a number as a string. you can use `alert( +d == 1436497200000)` to force a numerical comparison.

Comment: The bit you quote talks about the type of *x*, which is the *left hand* operand. Which in your case is not a string or number.

Comment: @brso05: That _"article"_ is a manual conversion of the _official_ EcmaScript standard.

Comment: @dandavis, ok, but why it doesn't work as the specification says? or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: "When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, *unless O is a Date object* (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String." - So when I try `alert(d == "Fri Jul 10 2015 13:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)")` it returns `true`.

Comment: @GetFree: you are reading it wrong. it is confusing. cerbrus is spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the spec at section [8.12.8](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.12.8), you will find this text near the end of the section:

> When the `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method of `O` is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were `Number`, ***unless*** `O` is a `Date` object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were `String`.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Now, in step `8` / `9` of the *The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm* <sup>[[11.9.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3)]</sup>, `ToPrimitive(x)` and `ToPrimitive(y)` are called without `hint` parameter.

The lack of this `hint` parameter, together with the above text, means that the `ToPrimitive` method returns the `toString()` value, on date objects.

As you're probably aware, `(new Date()).toString()` returns a string representation of the date in American English <sup>[[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString#Description)]</sup>:
`"Wed Jul 01 2015 22:08:41 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)"`

That a string like that doesn't equal `1436497200000` shouldn't come as a big surprise. ;-)

Comment: so `toPrimitive` is given no hint in this case, even though it's been compared to a number.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in steps 8 / 9 in section [11.9.3](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3), `ToPrimitive(x)` and `ToPrimitive(y)` are called without `hint` parameter. (Contrary to how it's called in section [11.8.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.5))

Answer (score 0):

ToPrimitive(A) attempts to convert its object argument to a primitive value, by attempting to invoke varying sequences of A.toString and A.valueOf methods on A.

So if the `toString()` call succeeds, it won't call `valueOf()`.